# What are difference between hostAttributes and properties in polymer?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm doing migration from 0.5 to 1.0.

While reading, I notice 2 different way on declaring attributes, using `hostAttributes` and `properties`.

What are difference between those 2 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Host attributes are attributes that do not match to an element's corresponding Javascript property (which you declare in `properties`). This includes attributes like `class`, `tabindex`, `data-*` attributes, aria-roles, etc. To declare them during create-time, you must set them in the `hostAttributes` object. If you are going to bind values into them, you must use `$=` (which calls `Element.setAttribute`) rather than `=`.

Sources:

- https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements.html#host-attributes
- https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#attribute-binding

Comment: Not class. The class attribute can't be configured using hostAttributes.

Answer (score 0):

If a custom element needs HTML attributes set on it at create-time, the attributes may be declared in a hostAttributes property on the prototype, where keys are the attribute names and values are the values to be assigned.

But now since listeners and hostAttributes have been removed from element metadata

we can use _ensureAttribute as an alternative to define these kind of attributes

ex:-

this._ensureAttribute('tabindex', 0);
you can declare all such properties in ready