# Why use host attributes in Polymer?

Tags: polymer-1.0

I'm currently reading the Polymer documents about [host attributes](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements.html#host-attributes),
and from what is written, there doesn't seem to be any solid reasoning behind them.

This is the only statement I could deduct from the docs:

> If a custom element needs HTML attributes set on it at create-time use hostAttributes

Which doesn't make too much sense in practicality to me.

Can anyone elaborate further on the topic? Or link to a more detailed documentation on their site if it exists.

*Edit:* I also read that they're not to be mistaken for properties and have a special notation for 2-way data binding.

Answer (score 0):

This is an unfortunate case of slight brevity in documentation. `hostAttributes` on a Polymer element are different to normal properties on the element in that they are set on the element during creation time. According to [the docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements#ready-method) (which have been updated since you asked this question):

> An element is ready when:
>
> - Its property values have been configured, with values data-bound from parents, deserialized from attribute values, or else set to their default value.

The important detail to note here is that the properties on the element are set *after* the creation time of the element, and before the `ready` callback. `hostAttributes` are set *before* the `created` callback, ie. during creation time.

`hostAttributes` behave the same way as attributes on native html elements do with regards to Polymer data binding. The "special notation", `attr$="value"`, is as such:

```
<!-- Polymer element -->
<my-el normal-property="[[myData1]]" host-attr$="[[myData2]]"></my-el>

<!-- Native element -->
<div hidden$="[[setDivHidden]]"></div>
```

> Why use host attributes in Polymer?

You may want the attributes to be available directly after creation of the element. It also conveys the semantics of the attributes as being static.

[Here is another answer which summarises the above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30723418/what-are-difference-between-hostattributes-and-properties-in-polymer)